# Can I define a variadic template function on a single type?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

Can I define a *variadic template function* not with a changing type, but just for a single one? If my goal is to define a function that only adds a variadic number of `int`, but not float, or anything else, can I do that with a `template<int....>` syntax somehow?

The multi-type sample I can put together easily:

```
int add() { return 0; }

template<typename T, typename... TS>
T add(T n, TS... m)
  { return n+add(m...); }
```

But how do I use `int` only in this?
It obviously can not follow the pattern to put `<int>` in the template-argument-list, because I want a function that takes arguments between the `(...)` and not between the `<...>` like this:

```
template<int n>
int constant() { return n; }

constant<4>();  // using the int-template function
```

It is obvious to me that the following will not work, therefore. But as a starting point...

```
template<int, int...>
int add(int n, int... m)    // error, of course.
  { return n+add(m...); }
```

How can I define `add` for `add(1)`, `add(1,2)`, `add(1,2,3)`  etc. but only for `int`-Arguments. It should not generate a `float`-function for `add(1.0)` (It may be that the call will work, but then only because `1.0` is converted to an `int`).

Note: I do not mean anything that would just constrain the type `T` or `TS` down with `enable_if` or such. I just think there might be a syntax for this kind of variadic templates that I miss here.

Comment: That's basically pointless just use `std::initializer_list`

Comment: @aaronman Oh man! Missing the obvious. Thank you. Why don't you make it an answer. Except, I need to write ´add({1,2,3})`, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this purpose you should really just use `std::initializer_list`, which is very similar to a variadic function for only one type.

```
int add(std::initializer_list<int> list) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (auto i : list) sum += i;
    return sum;
}
```

Now you can call it like this `int i = add({1,2,3,4,5,6});`

If you really want to you can easily put a static assert in that will do this for you.

```
int add() { return 0; }

template<typename T, typename... TS>
T add(T n, TS... m)
{
   static_assert(std::is_same<T,int>::value,"bad type"); 
   return n+add(m...); 
}
```

But IMO this totally defeats the purpose of variadic templates, and will make the program harder to read and write.

Comment: You are right of course. I just wanted to make sure I do not miss a syntactic piece of sugar.

Comment: `return i;` This string doesn't compile.

Comment: @Constructor sorry typo, fixed it

Comment: Using `initializer_list` disables narrowing conversions here; using `is_same` for the `static_assert` disables all conversions. To allow conversions (if you want to do that), you can use `is_convertible` and convert `return n+add(static_cast<int>(m)...);`. It is also possible to do a SFINAE-check to make the function template less greedy (e.g. if you have overloads).

Comment: @DyP too lazy,the initlists approach is better anyway, if you feel strongly about it u can answer or edit mine

Comment: No, it's fine, it's one way to do it. My comment intended to show alternatives, that's all.

Answer (score 3):

```
int add() { return 0; }

template<typename... TS>
int add(int n, TS... m)
{
    return n + add(m...); 
}
```

What is wrong with such code?

Comment: @aaronman It works only on those types which can be implicitly converted to `int` as well as your solution with initialiazer list.

Comment: with the initializer list it warns when something else is passed, your's doesn't

Comment: Actually, this is again a solution I did not think thought of, although it is kind of obvious. Yes, this is a variadic template that has to stop recursing on `int add()` and therefore relies on `int operator+(int)`, so to speak. And thus, finally, depending on the defiled global overloads of `operator+(int,...)` will be default work only with implicit convertibles. I guess this actually is what I wanted, and it has only a tiny change. As I stated in my question I would allow for implicit conversions, but can think of very good reasons to better choose the `initializer_list<int>`.

Comment: Guys, which answer should I accept now? Difficult. Constructor, I have to choose aaronmans answer, because it is more "answer-ish" (and not stated as a question). But you get your +1, of course.